# Why ceil() function return unexpected value?

Tags: c++

```
n = ceil(1234 / (double)1);
cout << n << endl;
```

Here output is `1234` but if I write

```
n = ceil(99999999999999999 / (double)1);
cout << n << endl;
```

This time I get `100000000000000000` as output. Why this happen?

Comment: What is the type of `n`?

Comment: `99999999999999999` can't be represented by a `double` so it gets rounded.

Comment: The warning given by [clang](https://godbolt.org/z/nP5PW7) explains it perfectly.

Comment: Just in passing, `(double)1` is usually written `1.0` (although some people use `1.`).